# Плагин в плагине не редактируется - Djangocms

Tags: django, django-cms

Ребята кто работал и работает с Djangocms: 
Тут дело такое, я создал два плагина
Первый: Карту
Второй: Коробку для карты
------— Все ок —----
Все отлично работает карты могу положит в коробку, но не могу редактировать карту в коробке

```
...


class MapsPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    module = _("Plugins")
    model = MapPluginModel
    name = _("Карта")
    render_template = False
    list_editable = True
    parent_classes = ['GroupMapsPlugin']


class GroupMapsPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    module = _("Plugins")
    name = _("Карты")
    render_template = "maps_plugin.html"
    cache = True
    allow_children = True
    child_classes = ["MapsPlugin"]

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        return context


plugin_pool.register_plugin(GroupMapsPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(MapsPlugin)
```

Comment: Что значит "не могу редактировать"?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в Djangocms есть такое (редактирование информации плагина)

Comment: Я в курсе. У вас не отображается кнопка редактирования в режиме структуры и не работает двойной клик в режиме содержимого?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev кнопка есть, нажимаю а оно не реагирует, и да даж е двойной клике в режиме содержание

Comment: В консоли браузера или в логах сервера есть что-нибудь?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev нету ни какого лог про это там и там, кнопка "карандаш" нажемается но нечего не происходит, все же думал что проблемы в описание этих плагинов код в вопросе. Проект закончу если разберусь с этим, но на зло в последном этапе это ))

Comment: Тогда у вас не диагностируемый баг. [Напишите](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues) об этом разработчикам. Возможно, они подскажут, как искать проблему, когда в логах пусто.